# class member template function passing a member specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am enhancing my learning on C++ template programming and after looking around I can't find any examples related to what I am trying to do.

I would like to call a templated member function passing it another templated member function but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

As an exercise, I have a class Foo that manages a Report.
I also have a class Bar that has Foo as a member via composition.
Bar is used by other classes (threads) to update a report on Foo by supplying an Update function (I know it breaks encapsulation :)

As a side, if there's a design pattern for something like this please suggest it.

I am trying to do something like below.
I just need to know the syntax for passing the specialised template member function and invoking it successfully. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: This code does not actually compile, it is just showing the idea I am trying to achieve, how to pass a member template function via another:**

```
struct T_Report{};
class Mutex{};


class Foo
{
public:
   template <typename T, void (T::*func)(T_Report&)> 
   void Update();

private:
   T_Report report;
   Mutex m_mutex();
};


template <typename T, void (T::*func)(T_Report&)>
void Foo::Update()
{
   // const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
   
   // call passed function here
   (T::*func)(T_Report &report);
};


class Bar
{
public:
   // passes through the call to Foo
   template <typename T, void (T::*F)(T_Report &)>
   void Update_Report<(T::*F)>() 
   { 
      m_foo.Update<(T::*F)>(); 
   };

private:
   class Foo m_foo;
};


class User
{
public:
   // user implements a function to update report - passed function
   Do_Update(T_Report &) {/*...*/};

   // indirectly start the report update by passing Update function
   void do_it()
   {
      m_bar.Update_Report<User, Do_Update>();
   };
   
private:
   Bar m_bar;
};
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you get compiler errors?

Comment: `};` can be just `}` after function definitions. `Do_Update(T_Report &)` does not compile.

Comment: I'd start with the basics: `(T::*func)(T_Report &report);` is not a function call. Here's [some good reading on the basics of using pointers to member functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Comment: Start with nailing down a non-template version.

Comment: A workaround is to use functor instead of a function. Basically a functor is a function encapsulated into a struct or class. You can then instanciate your template with the functor type.
The simplest functor can be a struct with your function defined as a static member function.

Comment: `m_bar.Update_Report<User, Do_Update>();` What `User` object do you want to end up calling the `Do_Update` function on?  Presumably `this`, but no where have you actually specified that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There many syntax errors in the code.
A template parameter can be a type (has the form : `typename T` or `class T`), of can be constant instance (has the form : `AKnownType objName`).
There are other forms (template, concepts, parameters packs..) but here there is 1 type parameter and 1 non type parameter.

I've commented and replaced with good syntax your code:

```
struct T_Report {};
class Mutex {};

class Foo
{
public:
   template <typename T, void (T::* func)(T_Report&)>
   void Update();

private:
   T_Report report;
   Mutex m_mutex();
};

// Need to define a type alias for 2nd template parameter
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
template<typename T>
using FPtr = void (T::*)(T_Report&);

////template <typename T, void (T::* func)(T_Report&)>
template<typename T,FPtr<T> func>
void Foo::Update()
{
   // call passed function here
   ////(T:: * func)(T_Report & report);
   (T{}.*func)( report );  // You must call the function on some T object
};


class Bar
{
public:
   // passes through the call to Foo
   ////template <typename T, void (T::* F)(T_Report&)>
   template <typename T,FPtr<T> func>
   ////void Update_Report<(T::* F)>()
   void Update_Report()
   {
      ////m_foo.Update<(T::* F)>();
      m_foo.Update<T,func>();
   };

private:
   class Foo m_foo;
};

class User
{
public:
   // user implements a function to update report - passed function
   ////Do_Update(T_Report&) {/*...*/ };
   void Do_Update(T_Report&) {/*...*/ };

   // indirectly start the report update by passing Update function
   void do_it()
   {
      ////m_bar.Update_Report<User, Do_Update>();
      m_bar.Update_Report<User,&User::Do_Update>();
   };

private:
   Bar m_bar;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost what I need. I want Foo::Update() to run User::Do_Update() on an existing User object. In your solution you instantiate a new object before calling (T{}.*func). The User object needs to be passed through and the member called through it..